# Update badge number when app is closed

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, push, badge

I am developing an iOS app that aims to receive push notifications as does *whatsapp*. But I do not know how to make the app when closed (idle, I do not mean in background), this update the badge counter. I can only send payload from a static number, but I can not update the total number of notifications.

I searched a lot but I've only found a way to upgrade from background or foreground but never when fully closed. However *whatsapp* can.

Thank you very much for your attention and apologies for my English.

Comment: I would recommend posting what you have tried. Your question at this point is very ambiguous in the sense it is asking about methodology and not a technical issue.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Already had similar questions, look for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551108/dismissing-ios-push-notifications-remotely?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872088/get-push-notification-while-app-in-foreground-ios?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679642/update-badge-icon?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693473/is-it-possible-to-update-badge-number-on-app-icon-without-openining-app-on-push?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be with silent push notification, in the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` you can remote your notification with the `[application setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:badgeNumber - 1];`
May be [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551108/dismissing-ios-push-notifications-remotely?rq=1) would help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

At the end I solved making a fresh registration notifications via database.
When sending a notification think an entry in the table and when the user opens the notification background I send a request to delete the entry.

By controlling notifications via database, I can send the payload with the updated badge.

Excuse my English, for me it is a problem writing in this language.